# Call SQL SP from dos batch file

Tags: sql-server-2005, dos

I have a MS SQL 2005 stored proc which takes an out parameter. How can I call this from a dos batch file and get the value of the out param? I know I have to use sqlcmd, but cant find anyting in there by which I can pass an out param and access its value in dos batch file.

Thanks
vikram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this kind of thing all the time (like so) with standard T-SQL, but you might be able to do something like this with a stored procedure if you edit the stored procedure to show a one line result set.

```
sqlcmd -b -S %COMPUTERNAME% -E -d %DBNAME% -Q "exec getXMLLocation;" -h-1 
   -o SearchResult.txt
  set /p URI=<SearchResult.txt
  @echo The XML file URI is: %URI%
```

Answer (score 0):

In DOS, you will get any information returned in the standard out, but you cannot easily manipulate this. Must this be DOS? Is PowerShell an option, as you have more capabilities with PowerShell (heck even WSH is a better option for DOS if you need to store this value and not just show it in the command prompt).

Adding this based on comment this must be DOS. Here are my thoughts:

---

First, I would use the out macro statement to direct to stdout:

```
: out stdout
```

Once you have output in stdout, you can use DOS commands to direct it to variables you have set up in DOS. stdout is handle 1 in DOS.

The one issue I can think that might make this fail is if other items are cluttering up stdout. I would not want to parse through a lot of junk.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It has to be DOS as the rest of the system is in DOS. Ideally, I want the returned value to be captured in a dos variable, so that I can run few checks on it.